# forecasting in R

Tags: r, rcpp, forecasting

l am trying to do the forecasting using R but everytime l download forecast package, it shows error that rcpp package isn't properly installed. As a result l am not able to run the forecast . Please can you tell me whats wrong or what l need to do.

Answer (score 5):

if `update.package` doesn't work try:

```
remove.packages(c('Rcpp','forecast'))
```

- Close R
- Open R

Then

```
install.packages(c('Rcpp','forecast'))
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably you should have posted the error message and some more info on your system/R version you are using but for a start try first updating the `Rcpp` package:

```
   update.packages('Rcpp')
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had issues with my anti-virus AVG interfering with an update (it hates `colorspace`, which is required for `ggplot2`). If a dependency is not installed that a package requires, the package installation will fail. The R session information will print what the failure package is.